# Xamarin Android Error "Can not resolve reference: `System.Dynamic`, referenced by `Microsoft.CSharp`"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

After years of happily using VS2019 for my Xamarin MVVMCross application, I am trying upgrade the Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise from 16.7.7 to 16.10.2, but upon building my Android Application i receive the following error:

**Can not resolve reference: `System.Dynamic`, referenced by `Microsoft.CSharp`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Dynamic`, or remove the reference to `Microsoft.CSharp`.  ClarityWork.Droid**

I have tried removing the reference to Microsot.CSharp in my Droid project and also removed the two places in my code where System.Dynamic was being used, but i am still getting the same error. I have also tried adding System.Dynamic.Runtime from NuGet to no avail

The error from the output window is as follows:

**3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(311,5): error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `System.Dynamic`, referenced by `Microsoft.CSharp`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Dynamic`, or remove the reference to `Microsoft.CSharp`.**

Has anyone else had a similar issue when upgrading VS2019 version? I have searched online and can't find any other references to it

Comment: Do you have this problem before upgrading Visual studio 2019?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I've never had the issue before with any version of VS2019.
VS2019 16.7.7 and all release versions i used previously work perfectly, it is just after upgrading to VS2019 16.10.2 that i have the problem

Comment: You can try to delete bin and obj file in your project, clean your project, and try to rebuild your project again. If it doesn't work, you can click **Help--Send feedback--Report a problem** to feedback this question.

Comment: That didn't work but I have reported and will update here with any remedy

Comment: Wait for your update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this was to add the NuGet package for Microsoft.CSharp to my .net standard core project